# What is the meaning of "away from this inclement air" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "away from this inclement air" in the following sentence,

> The state of her health is such that a return to her parents' house
>   seems prudent, **away from this inclement air**.

?

Does it mean "The state of her health is such that a return to her parents' house seems good. therefore, now, she is away from this inclement air" ?

What kind of grammar does sentences like this belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase 'away from this inclement air' is an adjective clause, describing 'her parents' house'. The house is 'away from this inclement air'. To illustrate the meaning by filling out the clause with a few more words, you could say

> The state of her health is such that a return to her parents' house seems prudent, where she will be away from this inclement air.